# parsing words from symbols on a list in python

Tags: python, list, parsing, symbols, words

I have to train a language model from a dataset of words. To this, I need to arrange all the text in only one column because is the only way the model works.  Until now I could split the document into one column as is required using Python without any problem.

For example:
Original document

> Zomer, 1951
>   De wereld bestond uit het wazige blauw van een wolkenloze
>   zomerhemel, het goudgroen van koel, geruststellend naaldbos en het
>   lijnrechte wit van de betonnen weg, die nieuw was, hij stond nog op
>   geen enkele kaart.

Document as required

```
Zomer, 
1951.
De 
wereld  
bestond 
uit  
het  
wazige 
blauw  
van  
een 
wolkenloze   
zomerhemel, 
het            
goudgroen 
van  
koel, 
geruststellend  
naaldbos 
en   
het      
lijnrechte     
wit   
van  
de    
betonnen    
weg,  
die 
nieuw    
was,  
hij  
stond   
nog   
op      
geen  
enkele  
kaart.
```

The problem started when I tried to take the symbols (comma, colon, semicolon, etc) into a new line and including an additional white space after each full stop (.)
For example:

```
Zomer
, 
1951
. 

De 
wereld
```

I haven’t found the appropriate way of doing this. Until now I have tried different ways using functions like `.split()` and `.find()`, among others, without any positive result. After opening the file:

```
 fileHandle = open("C:\Language Model\Corpora\Computing Clients 3.txt",'r')
```

I have tried with loops and conditions but nothing has worked. And all the results obtained until now are:

```
 AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find'
```

I know maybe I am missing something and that's why I'm asking you for your valuable help since the files are so huge and it would be useless do it manually knowing that Python can do it for me.

Comment: Please show the "loops and conditions" you have tried

Comment: How do you think anyone is gonna help without the relevant code?

Comment: I am pretty sure nltk has a method for it

Answer (score 3):

If the name of your file is **paragraph.txt** then

> f = open('paragraph.txt', 'r')
>
> words = []
>
> lines = f.readlines()
>
> for line in lines:
>
> ```
>    words.extend(line.split())
> ```

Above lines make a list of all words

And these are to remove . and , from those words

> for i in range(len(words)):
>
> ```
>     words[i] = words[i].replace('.' ,'')
>
>     words[i] = words[i].replace(',' ,'')
>
>     #here you can add a line to remove some other character
> ```

For printing the words :

> for word in words:
>
> ```
>     print(word)
> ```

Comment: @isedev: Hi, I found the error and I could run the code. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I implemented it to modify the special characters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve what you want if you ensure that punctuation is separated from text with a space. The regular expression with prepend a space before any non-alphanumeric character, so it can be `split` separately from any preceding word.

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "Zomer, 1951 De wereld bestond uit het wazige blauw van een wolkenloze zomerhemel, het goudgroen van koel, geruststellend naaldbos en het lijnrechte wit van de betonnen weg, die nieuw was, hij stond nog op geen enkele kaart."
>>> text2 = re.sub(r'([^a-zA-Z0-9-]+)',r' \1',text)
>>> text2
'Zomer , 1951  De  wereld  bestond  uit  het  wazige  blauw  van  een  wolkenloze  zomerhemel , het  goudgroen  van  koel , geruststellend  naaldbos  en  het  lijnrechte  wit  van  de  betonnen  weg , die  nieuw  was , hij  stond  nog  op  geen  enkele  kaart .'
>>> text2.split()
['Zomer',                                                                       
 ',',                                                                           
 '1951',                                                                        
 'De',                                                                          
 'wereld',
 'bestond',
 'uit',
 'het',
 'wazige',
 'blauw',
 'van',
 'een',
 'wolkenloze',
 'zomerhemel',
 ',',
 'het',
 'goudgroen',
 'van',
 'koel',
 ',',
 'geruststellend',
 'naaldbos',
 'en',
 'het',
 'lijnrechte',
 'wit',
 'van',
 'de',
 'betonnen',
 'weg',
 ',',
 'die',
 'nieuw',
 'was',
 ',',
 'hij',
 'stond',
 'nog',
 'op',
 'geen',
 'enkele',
 'kaart',
 '.']
```

Comment: @fnokke and moter I'm not a programmer and I started working in this field some days ago and I just realized how important is to save everything you do, but i didn't with what I tried. So the only code I finally have is the one used to split the document, sorry.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I followed your code and now I trying to understand the error message : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Language Model/Corpora/answers.py", line 9, in <module>
    text2 = re.sub(r'([^a-zA-Z0-9-]+)',r' \1',text)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 151, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or buffer.                                      Now I'm checking the meaning of all of this and I will let you know if I can solve it or not.